# Is it possible to retrieve the password from a user Graph API in Azure AD?

Tags: azure, graph

The question is very simple, Is it possible to retrieve the password from a user Graph API in Azure AD?.

So having the Graph API I noticed you can reset passwords from users but what I want to do, it is to be able to create my own sign-in page in Javascript or Java so I can pass the user name and password of a particular user and Authenticate that particular entity.

I am ok passing the ClientID and the Secret Key id so I can manage the Graph Api quite easily with the bearer token... but again, can I check a password for a user?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No,

You cannot retrieve the password for any user in Azure AD in any way. But you can use [ADAL JavaScript](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/10/28/adal-javascript-and-angularjs-deep-dive/) to create your own login page.